# Multi return statement STRANGE?

Tags: c#, return, decompiling

Today while playing with a De-compiler, i Decompiled the .NET C# Char Class and there is a strange case which i don't Understand

```
public static bool IsDigit(char c)
{
    if (char.IsLatin1(c) || c >= 48)
    {
        return c <= 57;
    }
    return false;
    return CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == 8;//Is this Line Reachable if Yes How does it work !
}
```

i Used **Telerik JustDecompile**

Comment: No, it's not reachable.  Perhaps someone compiled without optimizations so the IL is there, and the decompiler grabs it verbatim.

Comment: What version of the .NET framework is this from and what decompiler did you use?

Comment: @Adam Huldsworth maybe you should write that Comment as a Answer so later i could possibly mark as correct !

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile

Comment: I experienced similar issued with JustDecompile.  The Telerik product is still new and appear to contain bugs.  I stick to the RedGate product for now, but others soom to have great success with other decompilers also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think your decompiler might be dodgy... With Reflector I get:

```
public static bool IsDigit(char c)
{
   if (!IsLatin1(c))
   {
       return (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber);
   }
   return ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'));
}
```

And with ILSpy I get:

```
public static bool IsDigit(char c)
{
   if (char.IsLatin1(c))
   {
      return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
   }
   return CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber;
}
```

Comment: damn Reflector is outputting the Negation of ILSpy LOL !

Comment: Im Marking this Answer as right ,but all of the answers are correct ,but yours has Output from 2 Compiler's so im going to mark as Correct .

Comment: I always favour quantity over quality. 8oP

Answer (score 2):

I assume that this is a bug in the decompiler you used.

In the .NET 4.0 framework, IL Spy shows the following code:

```
public static bool IsDigit(char c)
{
    if (char.IsLatin1(c))
    {
        return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
    }
    return CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c)
           == UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber;
}
```

Comment: So we find that Reflector and IlSpy are the best ones :-)

Comment: I like the output of ILSpy a bit more, it looks cleaner - although it is technically the same.

Comment: Me too, because he checks a positive instead of a negative.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the decompiler you used isn't very good at what it's doing.

Here's the output of [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) for that method:

```
public static bool IsDigit(char c)
{
  if (!char.IsLatin1(c))
    return CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber;
  if ((int) c >= 48)
    return (int) c <= 57;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: im Using Teleric Just-Decompiler

Comment: Now you know: Don't use it anymore ;-)

Comment: dotPeek doesn't always give correct solutions as well, but when a decompiler gives results that are obviously wrong, it's always a good idea to check with a different decompiler (or take a look at the IL).

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth Never again :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your decompiler lies.

dotPeek code:

```
public static bool IsDigit(char c)
    {
      if (char.IsLatin1(c))
      {
        if ((int) c >= 48)
          return (int) c <= 57;
        else
          return false;
      }
      else
        return CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber;
    }
```